# Extract text from unselected PDF content using java PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I can easily get the content from the PDF file, but I got some file which text is not selectable when I open it. My existing code doesn't able to extract those text with following code block -

```
public class PDFBoxExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\pdf\\pdf_result.pdf");
            try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(file))) {
                document.getClass();
                if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
                    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
                    stripper.setSortByPosition(false);
                    stripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(true);
                    PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

                    String content = tStripper.getText(document);
                    System.out.println(content);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the following link of my pdf file-
[https://1drv.ms/b/s!AmRKaLhGJhJphvMOUBGADveatrx0hA?e=a0se](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AmRKaLhGJhJphvMOUBGADveatrx0hA?e=a0seG7)G7

Can you please provide some solution for the same.

Comment: No text is drawn as text in your PDF, only tons of small bitmap images on which some text has been rendered. Thus, your PDF is no candidate for text extraction (or text stripping as called in PDFBox) but for OCR. (If the source of that PDF promised extractable text, you can complain and request a PDF with actual text.)

Comment: When I open this file in Microsoft Word, then we can able to see the data in text format. You mean Microsoft Word automatically convert image to Text when I open this file.

Comment: *"You mean Microsoft Word automatically convert image to Text when I open this file."* - Yes, apparently it applies OCR.

Comment: Ohkk I understand. Do you have any java solution to extract the images from this pdf files and get the text using OCR?